# responsive-calendar: select days with events using jquery

Tags: jquery, calendar

I'm using this jquery based calendar http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/ and I want to get all days that have events and change their background color.

The problem is that I can't even get the span that contains the number of events which is inside the day div.

Just for testing I've tried to just get or to change the text or just hide it but nothing works.

It seems that it is the calendar itself that doesn't allow its items to be selected using jquery.

The selectors I've already tested to get the span using its class since it does not have an id are:

```
$('.badge')
$('span.badge')
$('span.badge.badge-warning')
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I found a way to sovle it! I wrote a function that checks if the element is loaded:

```
window.setTimeout(checkForElement, 500);

  function checkForElement() {
          var element = $('.badge.badge-warning').parent().children('a');
          if (element.length) {
                  doSomething();
                  return;
          } else
                  window.setTimeout(checkForElement, 500);
  }

  function doSomething() {
          $('.badge.badge-warning').parent().children('a').css('background-color','green');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would access days like this:

```
$('.badge.badge-warning').parent().children('a').css('background-color', 'red')
```

And use it with 'onInit' callback to run the command when days are actually loaded.